# Wordpress Add actions and filters only if certain condition met

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I am customizing wordpress comments to add multiple custom fields. So i have added filters and actions to show fields, validate them, process them and finally show them in comments. I have written these and they are working fine.

However i only need them only for Post which belongs to specific category and comment is not a reply of any other comment.

I tried few things but nothing seems to work. Can somebody provide me a working solution.

Comment: Hi, do you mean in frontend? So you want those extra fields to show only if user is viewing a post or a post-archive of a certain category?

Comment: Yes on front end as well. I simply want to hide those filters and action if it doesn't met the condition. i.e i want to wrap all that code in a condition if(condition){all my code}. So that, that functionality only available to my specific condition met only.

Comment: and how about putting conditions inside the filters instead of filters inside conditions (this is the usual way)? And can you post 1 filter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to start, I think you could put conditions inside filters and not filters inside conditions. That said, for posts in category and category archives you can use the 'conditional tags' `is category` (for archive) and `in_category` (for posts):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

Comment: Yes that's in my mind as well but with this i have to put condition in 4 places, that's why i asked for a better solution. Anyways its a working solution so +1.

Comment: maybe you could put conditions directly on the theme templates when generating the comments code.

Comment: To make things simple i used condition inside filters as you said.